# How do I display data on a text field upon selection of an option in a form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have been trying to update a field. Bid price and offer price are the fields I want to update. The selections are gbp/usd, eur/usd, etc. I would like to define the text field with variables like `$bid`, `$bid1`, `bid2`, etc. which are already predefined. Can someone help me with this?

This is my code.

```php
<?php
$timestamp=time();set_time_limit (0);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<form action ="price.php" method="post">


<p>Symbol : <select name="currency_pair">
<option value="gbp/usd">GBP/USD</option>
<option value="eur/usd">EUR/USD</option>
<option value="usd/cad">USD/CAD</option>
<option value="usd/chf">USD/CHF</option>
<option value="usd/jpy">USD/JPY</option>
<option value="eur/chf">EUR/CHF</option>
<option value="eur/jpy">EUR/JPY</option>
<option value="aud/usd">AUD/USD</option>

</select></p>
<p> Date : <input type="datetime" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d ",$timestamp); ?>" name="date"/>    </p>
<p> Type : <input type="radio" name="type" value="buy">Buy 
<input type="radio" name="type" value="sell">Sell
<p> Size : <input type="number"pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01"name="size"/></p>
<p> Bid Price : <input type="number" step="any" readonly name="entry" value="<?php if  ($currency_pair=="gbp/usd"){echo bid;}elseif($currency_pair=="eur/usd"){echo bid2;};?>" >
Offer Price<input type="number" step="any" readonly="yes" name="entry" value="<?php if ($currency_pair=="gbp/usd"){echo bid;}elseif($currency_pair=="eur/usd"){echo bid2;};?>" ></p>
<p> Stop Loss : <input type="number"step="any" name="stoploss"/></p>
<p> Take Profit : <input type="number"step="any"name="takeprofit"/></p>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script>
</script>   </body> </html>
```

Comment: Can you correct the errors first? For instance, `<form action ="price.php" method="post"/>` may not do what you think it does. Also, a submit button outside of a form will not work. And you have more errors, but those are not as problematic.

Comment: Please note that once a php page is loaded,further php code parsing will not happen until refreshed or called again.So u will have to make ajax calls so that u can update the text field contents.

Comment: Yes i do understand that and i have done that on a another page. I am trying to find out how i can allow the 2 texts field display the variable values. My variable are $bid , $bid1 , $bid2 , $bid3,etc. how do i assign the selected options to each 2 variable so i can display in the 2 text box??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is PHP-preprocessed version of the code, which contains only HTML and JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<form action ="price.php" method="post"/>
<form>
<p>Symbol : <select name="currency_pair" id="select_pair" onchange="pair_selected()">
<option value="gbp/usd">GBP/USD</option>
<option value="eur/usd">EUR/USD</option>
<option value="usd/cad">USD/CAD</option>
</select></p>
<script>
var courses = {};
courses['gbp/usd'] = [ 10, 15 ];
courses['eur/usd'] = [ 14, 16 ];
courses['usd/cad'] = [ 21, 23 ];
function pair_selected() { // to change your edits
    var e = document.getElementById("select_pair");
    var pair = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var course = courses[pair];
    document.getElementById("bid").value = course[0];
    document.getElementById("offer").value = course[1];
}
window.onload = function() { pair_selected(); } // to init your edits
</script>

<p> Date : <input type="datetime" value="1970-01-01 " name="date"/> </p>
<p> Type : <input type="radio" name="type" value="buy">Buy 
<input type="radio" name="type" value="sell">Sell
<p> Size : <input type="number"pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01"name="size"/></p>
**<p> Bid Price : <input id="bid" type="number" step="any" readonly name="entry" value="" >
   Offer Price<input id="offer" type="number" step="any" readonly="yes" name="entry" value="" ></p>**
<p> Stop Loss : <input type="number"step="any" name="stoploss"/></p>
<p> Take Profit : <input type="number"step="any"name="takeprofit"/></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Tested and works in IE 8-10, Firefox, Chrome, Opera 15 and Safari

Comment: WOW Thanks!!! i managed to do it already , but do you know how i make them refreshable(text field) ? because they are live data.

Comment: Making data 'live' is not so simple. You will need to run [AJAX-call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to retrieve new data periodically (from server script) Or even use [server push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get a framework. The most commonly used framework is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Secondly, I would look here for the code on how to get the selected text: [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Finally, you should bind the relvant code to the corresponding event. In `jQuery` that is the `change()` event.

**Example**

```
$('#currency_pair').change(function() {
    // Note: 'currency_pair' should be an ID, not a name.
    $('#textBox').text($('#currency_pair').val());
});
```

This should go in a separate file, and it should be linked into your HTML via the `script` tag, which you can find a tutorial on here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Answer (score 0):

It is answered here:

[Change input class of textbox onchange dropdown List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645873/change-input-class-of-textbox-onchange-dropdown-list)
Play around the code to check what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use one PHP **array**, not separate variables $bid, $bid2, ...
2. You should generate Javascript data structure (object of arrays in code below, but this can vary) from your PHP array
3. You should use event `onchange` of your `select` to lookup Javascript data structure, find there appropriate data (for user selection) and substitute it into your edits
4. Learning and using **framework like jquery** instead of pure JS would be simpler and better, so it is **recommended**, but not obligatory. Code below is using only pure JS, because you did not mention knowledge or usage of any framework in your question.

Here is the code:

```
<?
$timespamp = time();
$conversions = array(
    "gbp/usd" => array(10,15),
    "eur/usd" => array(14,16),
    "usd/cad" => array(21,23)
    // and so on
);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<form action ="price.php" method="post"/>
<form>
<p>Symbol : <select name="currency_pair" id="select_pair" onchange="pair_selected()">
<? foreach( $conversions as $pair=>$course ) { ?>
<option value="<?=$pair?>"><?=strtoupper($pair)?></option>
<? } ?>
</select></p>
<script>
var courses = {};
<? foreach( $conversions as $pair=>$course ) { ?>
courses['<?=$pair?>'] = [ <?=$course[0]?>, <?=$course[1]?> ];
<? } ?>
function pair_selected() { // to change your edits
    var e = document.getElementById("select_pair");
    var pair = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var course = courses[pair];
    document.getElementById("bid").value = course[0];
    document.getElementById("offer").value = course[1];
}
window.onload = function() { pair_selected(); } // to init your edits
</script>

<p> Date : <input type="datetime" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d ",$timestamp); ?>" name="date"/> </p>
<p> Type : <input type="radio" name="type" value="buy">Buy 
<input type="radio" name="type" value="sell">Sell
<p> Size : <input type="number"pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01"name="size"/></p>
**<p> Bid Price : <input id="bid" type="number" step="any" readonly name="entry" value="" >
   Offer Price<input id="offer" type="number" step="any" readonly="yes" name="entry" value="" ></p>**
<p> Stop Loss : <input type="number"step="any" name="stoploss"/></p>
<p> Take Profit : <input type="number"step="any"name="takeprofit"/></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I know what do i place in the (?>) ?

Comment: PHP code is inside <? ?> brackets, HTML and JS code is outside. As a whole it works "like template". When PHP code is executed, <? ?> blocks control flow and generate some (maybe empty) output to form HTML+JS document.
For example, <?=$v1+$v2?> outputs value of expression ($v1+$v2)
Please, read PHP docs for more detailed explanation.

Comment: oh.. i have tried the code. it doesnt seem to work , the selection of $currency_pair.

Comment: Code was tested before posting here - in local HTM file with Firefox browser, using online sandbox for PHP preprocessing (codepad.org), and it works for me